# как сделать UNIT тесты

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

Готовлюсь к собеседованию, помогите плиз разобраться с тестами. Например как можно протестить эту функцию

```
    var str = "2015-04-21T06:50:21";

    function covertDate(str) {
    var options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        weekday: 'long',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric'
    };
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(Date.parse(str));
    date = date.toLocaleString("ru", options);
    return date;
}
```

Делаю на нативном JS, подключил Mocha и chai, а как юзать разобраться не могу.
Мб есть более автоматические варианты?

Comment: Врядли вас будут спрашивать на собеседовании `JavaScript` про unit-тесты. Скорее от них будут открещиваться как от демонов.

Comment: Да мне просто сбросили тестовое задание, я сделал всё кроме последнего пункта - "Код должен быть покрыт юнит тестами"

Comment: оу, значит наоборот. Я бы очень осторожно относился к таким работодателям) Но если уж очень хотите - суть тестов, это провести некие assert-ы работы методов класса, у вас возможно это будут функции, что проще. assert - есть простое сравнение: то есть проверка, что функция вернёт заданный результат, если ей скормить заданные аргументы. Вот например почитайте тут  http://iantonov.me/page/uchimsja-testirovat-svoj-javascript-kod , можно обойтись даже без библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо, а если функция отрабатывает и ничего не возвращает, для таких тоже стоит писать тесты?

Comment: Функция может ничего не возвращать, но она на что-то будет влиять. Это `что-то` вам и надо проверить. Но главное запомните, unit-тесты в JS могут пропагандировать только люди которые совсем не разбираются в программировании но умеют гуглить, либо те которые готовы отдать в 3 раза больше денег за избыточную стабильность и повесить на вас очень нудную работу (например банки).

Comment: Благодарю за инфу для размышления)